# Getting list of null values when retrieveing list of child entities in hibernate using bidirectional @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

I have problem when accessing list of child entities in my @OneToMany association in hibernate.
I am able to load the parent object using successfully

```
from Exam query
```

But when i try to access the list of child entities using the its getters.
Im getting list of null values..

Here is my code for Exam Entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="EXAM_ID")
private Long examID;
@Column(name="EXAM_TITLE")
private String title;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="question", targetEntity=Question.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Question> examQuestion = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

Here is for Question entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="QUESTION_ID")
private Long questionID;
@Column(name="QUESTION")
private String question;
@Column(name="ANSWER")
private String answer;
@Column(name="ANSWER_TYPE")
private String answerType;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="EXAM_ID")
private Exam exam;
```

Am i missing something?..thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `mappedBy="exam"` on association instead of `mappedBy="question"`.

Comment: Thanks..a very silly mistake of me..Thanks for the reply..:))